# How to customize url for splash page

Tags: javascript, splash-screen

here in example http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/dynamicsplash.htm

when open it have to click "Skip to content" for go to page.

but i want url direct to page without wait or click "Skip to content"

```
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/dynamicsplash.htm?Skip_to_content
```

Comment: The "Skip to content" page is in the same page. So there is no any redirection. If you check the `HTML` you can see that there is a `div` which appears on the 'original' site.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan it possible to create url to run function close

Comment: ex : `http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/dynamicsplash.htm?Skip_to_content`

Comment: As I know there is no "normal and easy" way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got some idea from my friend and all you guy, so i can do it now and here my changed.

### html url for skip to content

```
<a href="javascript:parent.window.location='http://domain.com?skip=true'" >Skip to content</a>
```

### browser url for skip to content

```
http://domain.com?skip=true
```

### index.html

```
<!-- splash or intro page -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/splashpage.js"></script>
<script>   
    function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
        var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
            var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
            if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
                return KeyValuePair[1];
            }
        }    
    }

    if (GetUrlValue('skip') == 'true') {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            splashpage.closeit();
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Note :** u can use this url in ifram page also

**source :** http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/dynamicsplash.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bookmarklet to present the url in an iframe or load it using ajax and then execute js code to close the ad when loading is finished. While most browsers support bookmarklets, note that they are not normal urls. You have to actually create a bookmark entry in the browser with the js code set in the "location field". It will work only when you click on the button for the bookmarklet. It will not work simply by pasting the code in the browser's location field. So for sharing purposes this is not as convenient as sharing a normal url. But it is convenient if you are accessing that page frequently and are tired of closing that ad.